# LibGDX: Using SpriteBatches when looping

Tags: java, android, performance, libgdx, sprite

I have a 2d array of Sprites that contains approx. 50 sprites. I want to draw them all in the render method. I don't know what will give me the best performance. These are the two alternatives I've come up with:

```
batch.begin();
for(Sprite[] row : sprite2d) {
    for(Sprite cell : row) {
        cell.draw(batch);
    }
}
batch.end();
```

Or:

```
for(Sprite[] row : sprite2d) {
    for(Sprite cell : row) {
        batch.begin();
        cell.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

I suppose the first alternative is better because I don't start the batch over and over again. On the other hand, I'm not sure whether it's good practive to loop inside the batch.begin() - batch.end() part.

Or is there another alternative that gives better performance?

Thank you for your answers,

Tony

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should definitely prefer the first variant. `SpriteBatch` will internally send the calls to OpenGL in bundles as soon as this is necessary. If you call `batch.end()`, you will force the `SpriteBatch` to send the pending OpenGL commands during each loop.

The expensive code is contained in the private method `SpriteBatch#renderMesh()`, which will be called by SpriteBatch automatically each time it is necessary to flush the OpenGL commands. If you need to flush the commands for whatever reason, you can also do so explicitly by calling `SpriteBatch#flush()`, which would still be less expensive then ending the SpriteBatch by calling `SpriteBatch#end()`.